# Consuming SOAP service with NET 6 Blazor WASM - Error in ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, soap, service, blazor, endpoint

I'm working with Blazor WebAssembly in Net 6, trying to consume a web service SOAP.
The Blazor app is configure to HTTPs, but the SOAP service no.

In the Reference.cs, there is a line where crash with an error:

```
System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
```

And the error is:

**The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ChannelBindingUtility' threw an exception.**

One part of the Reference.cs of the service is:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IMyService))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                return result;
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IMyService))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://MyService.svc");
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
        {
            return MyServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IMyService);
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
        {
            return MyServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IMyService);
        }

        public enum EndpointConfiguration
        {

            BasicHttpBinding_IMyService,
        }
```

There is a chance to consume a SOAP service properly?
Should I register the service in Program.cs?

Help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is little chance of success here. Blazor Wasm network i/o is limited to a specially configured HttpClient. Maybe you could set up a custom binding with that  but that won't be easy. Basically a browser app is the wrong place for WCF.

Comment: If this is a new project then look beyond WCF. If the service is locked in on SOAP then use an API as intermediate.